# C++/MySQL - 'Unknown MySQL server host' when accessing database via host address; Don't have an IP

Tags: php, c++, mysql, exception

I have a database set up in my 1and1-package and I want to connect to it in a c++ application. It works just fine in PHP.

The problem is, I don't have the actual IP of the database, all I have is the host address and the login details:

**Hostname:** db12345678.db.1and1.com

**Username:** dbo12345678

**Password:** mypassword

I'm using the MySQL C++ Connector 1.1.4. Here's my code for testing purposes:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib,"mysqlcppconn.lib")

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    try {
        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *con;
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;

        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect(sql::SQLString("db12345678.db.1and1.com"),sql::SQLString("dbo12345678"),sql::SQLString("mypassword"));
        con->setSchema("test");
    }
    catch(sql::SQLException &e)
    {
        std::cout<<"Exception: "<<e.what()<<std::endl;
    }
    while(true);
    return 0;
}
```

Using the host address I get the following output:

```
Exception: Unknown MySQL server host 'db12345678.db.1and1.com' (0)
```

I've also tried "tcp://db12345678.db.1and1.com", "tcp://db12345678.db.1and1.com:3306", "db12345678.db.1and1.com:3306", the error messages differ but the end-result is the same.

I've tried pinging the host and getting through with a traceroute to get the IP, but that doesn't work.

What else can I try?

Comment: Is remote access to your database allowed?

Comment: I can access it via PHP on a different host, so I'm assuming it is.

Comment: What about using your PHP host to get the IP address of your MySQL server then?

Comment: The only information about the MySQL server I can get from the PHP object is some "host_info", which is just a string with the host name: "db12345678.db.1and1.com via TCP/IP"

Comment: What's the result of `$ip = gethostbyname('db12345678.db.1and1.com');? Is it the same name or is it an IP address? See the documentation to [gethostbyname](http://php.net/manual/de/function.gethostbyname.php)

Comment: Hmm... That does give me an IP, however I still can't connect using that. Although this time the message is "Can't connect to MySQL server on '123.45.678.910' (10060)'. I tried the same IP with my PHP code, and again, that worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Today I ran in to a wierd problem with the MySQL C++ Connector where it would not accept my host..

This is how I got things working :

```
sql::ConnectOptionsMap connection_properties;

try {

    sql::Statement *stmt;

    connection_properties ["hostName"] = std::string("host.com");      
    connection_properties ["userName"] = std::string("dbuser");
    connection_properties ["password"] = std::string("dbpass");
    connection_properties ["schema"] = std::string("dbname");
    connection_properties ["OPT_RECONNECT"] = true;


    /* Create a connection */
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect(connection_properties);  

 } catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
    std::cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
    std::cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
    std::cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
    std::cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Oddly, I cannot figure out why am I getting un-handled exception from sql::ConnectOptionsMap.